# Replicating a SQL WITH statement query in Linq to Entities

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm looking to recreate a query that works for me when I wrote it in SQL but I cannot find out how to recreate in LINQ.  I am trying to get the latest logon record for each user on the system.  It is part of a search function so there will be WHEREs added onto the query.  This SQL does what I want it to do

```
with latest_logon_for_each_user as (select user_id as userId, max(logon_date) as maxLatestLogon
    from licence
    group by fk_user_id)
    select * 
    from licence ul join users u on ul.fk_user_id = u.id,
    latest_logon_for_each_user 
    where ul.fk_user_id = userId and ul.date_of_latest_logon = maxLatestLogon
    order by ul.id;
```

Each person can have more than 1 licence and I'm trying to return the last licence that was used.  Is there a way to create this query using LINQ to Entities?  Is there a better way to write the query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
var result = (from u in users
                                from ul in licences
                                where u.id == ul.user_id
                                && ul.logon_date == ((from d in licences where u.id == d.user_id select d.logon_date).Max())
                                select new QueryItem()
                                {
                                    id = u.id,
                                    logon_date = ul.logon_date
                                }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Below is a consoleApp I wrote for your question:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverFlowConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<users> users = new List<users>()
            {
                new users(){id =1},
                new users(){id =2},
                new users(){id =3}

            };

            List<licence> licences  = new List<licence>()
            {
                new licence(){user_id=1, logon_date=DateTime.Today},
                new licence(){user_id=1, logon_date=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3)},
                new licence(){user_id=1, logon_date=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)},
                new licence(){user_id=1, logon_date=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2)},
                new licence(){user_id=2, logon_date=DateTime.Today},
                new licence(){user_id=3, logon_date=DateTime.Today}
            };

            var result = (from u in users
                                from ul in licences
                                where u.id == ul.user_id
                                && ul.logon_date == ((from d in licences where u.id == d.user_id select d.logon_date).Max())
                                select new QueryItem()
                                {
                                    id = u.id,
                                    logon_date = ul.logon_date
                                }).Distinct().ToList();


        }

        class licence
        {
            public int user_id { get; set; }            
            public DateTime logon_date { get; set; }

        }

        class users 
        {
            public int id { get; set; }

        }

        class QueryItem
        {

            public int id { get; set; }

            public DateTime logon_date { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```